# Normal distribution bound

Tags: inequality, normal-distribution

Let $X$ be a random variable which follows normal distribution.
Is True that

$Pr[|X|\leq \epsilon] \leq \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon \geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

For the case $\epsilon\geq 0.5$ it's obvious that the strict inequality will hold (if X is standard normal). So you should actually show  $P \Big[|X|\leq\epsilon\Big]\leq \epsilon$, for all $\epsilon<0.5$ .

Comment: Can you please explain why it is obvious if $\epsilon \geq 0$.

Comment: Due to symmetry of the standard normal distribution you have that $P\Big[|X|\leq\epsilon\Big]=2P\Big[X\leq\epsilon\Big]\leq\epsilon$. So $P\Big[X\leq\epsilon\Big]\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. But $P\Big[X\leq\epsilon\Big]$ and also $P\Big[|X|\leq\epsilon\Big]$ are probabilities which implies the strict inequality for $\epsilon\geq 0.5$.